# Why is my Newton's Method function returning None?

Tags: python

```
def evaluatePoly(poly, x):
    '''
    Computes the value of a polynomial function at given value x. Returns that
    value as a float.

    poly: list of numbers, length > 0
    x: number
    returns: float
    '''
    for n in range(len(poly)):
        poly[n] = (poly[n]) * (x**n)

    return float(sum(poly[:]))

def computeDeriv(poly):
    '''
    Computes and returns the derivative of a polynomial function as a list of
    floats. If the derivative is 0, returns [0.0].

    poly: list of numbers, length &gt; 0
    returns: list of numbers (floats)

    >>> print computeDeriv([-13.39, 0.0, 17.5, 3.0, 1.0])
    [0.0, 35.0, 9.0, 4.0]
    >>> print computeDeriv([6, 1, 3, 0])
    [1.0, 6.0, 0.0]
    >>> print computeDeriv([20])
    [0.0]

    '''
    if len(poly) == 1:
        poly = [0.0]
        return poly
    for m in range(len(poly)):
        poly[m] = float(m) * poly[m]
    return poly[1:]

def computeRoot(poly, x_0, epsilon):
    '''
    Uses Newton's method to find and return a root of a polynomial function.
    Returns a list containing the root and the number of iterations required
    to get to the root.

    poly: list of numbers, length > 1.
         Represents a polynomial function containing at least one real root.
         The derivative of this polynomial function at x_0 is not 0.
    x_0: float
    epsilon: float > 0
    returns: list [float, int]

    >>> print computeRoot([-13.39, 0.0, 17.5, 3.0, 1.0], 0.1,  .0001)
    [0.806790753796352, 7]
    >>> print computeRoot([1, 9, 8], -3, .01)
    [-1.0000079170005467, 5]
    >>> print computeRoot([1, -1, 1, -1], 2, .001)
    [1.0002210630197605, 4]
    '''
    x = x_0
    iter = 0
    list = []
    polyStart = poly[:]
    while abs(evaluatePoly(poly, x)) >= epsilon:
        poly = polyStart[:]
        l = evaluatePoly(poly,x)
        if abs(l) < epsilon:
            list.append(x)
            list.append(iter)
            return list
        else:
            poly = polyStart[:]
            d = computeDeriv(poly)
            dn = evaluatePoly(d, x)
            x = (x - (l/dn))
            iter = iter + 1
```

Comment: I see code but I don't see a question.

Comment: You may wish to ask this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as it's not really a question with a specific problem

Comment: its for homework.  And the autochecker is giving me the result of None.  But, python is giving me all the right answers.  Why would the autochecker result in None?

Comment: @Kevin You should put as much information about that as possible in the actual question. Which function? What inputs?

Comment: Sorry, first time doing this.  For the computeRoot function.  I am getting the proper answers to my test values.  The first two functions work perfect.  My homework is submitted online and it goes through an auto-checker.  The online autochecker is returning a 'None' value on the computeRoot function.  But, when I run it on python 2 and 3 it returns me a proper list.  So, I don't know if the autochecker is broken or my code is broken.

Comment: @Kevin Do you know the input it used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean this function is returning `None` on some particular input:

```
def computeRoot(poly, x_0, epsilon):
    x = x_0
    iter = 0
    list = []
    polyStart = poly[:]
    while abs(evaluatePoly(poly, x)) >= epsilon:
        poly = polyStart[:]
        l = evaluatePoly(poly,x)
        if abs(l) < epsilon:
            list.append(x)
            list.append(iter)
            return list
        else:
            poly = polyStart[:]
            d = computeDeriv(poly)
            dn = evaluatePoly(d, x)
            x = (x - (l/dn))
            iter = iter + 1
```

How do I know? Because there's only one `return`, and it's not at the end of the function. If `abs(evaluatePoly(poly, x)) >= epsilon` is `False`, then the `while` loop will end, and there's nothing after it, so the function ends and returns `None` by default (any function which doesn't explicitly `return` returns `None`).

So, you need to figure out what the correct return value is in that situation and add a `return` statement and the end of the function.

Comment: This is why I added the if loop.  The while loop was infinite and I couldn't figure out why.  It should of stopped before I through the if statement in.  I know its redundant, but I couldnt figure out why the while loop didnt stop at less than epsilon but the for loop does.

Comment: Closing the while loop worked for the checker. I closed out the while loop with.. list.append(x) list.append(iter)
return list.  Thanks Brendan.

Comment: @Kevin What if they intentionally used a value where your first guess is correct? You'd never enter the `while` loop, so your inner checks wouldn't help.

Comment: They list the test values they use and the results given for like 15 tests.  So, originally they were all coming up none.  But, when I tested the values on Python they worked.

Comment: @Kevin I think you can fix your `while` by just moving the copy into it: `while abs(evaluatePoly(poly[:], x)) >= epsilon`, since copying the list (`[:]`) is the only difference.

Comment: Quick question though.  WHY... Do I need that if loop in the while loop for it to even end.  It was infinite in python without it.  Or, did I mess something up?

Comment: I'll try that real quick... ignore above ^.

Comment: @Kevin An even better solution would be to do the copy inside the functions, so you don't need to worry about it every time you call them.

Comment: Nope.  I copied the list because that list has to stay the same.  But e mutated through the loop.  I still can't get a single while loop to end.  But the autochecker says I can move on.  It's gonna irk me that I can't figure it out right this second but I got a hangman program to write.

Comment: @Kevin What I mean is that since your list needs to stay the same, your functions shouldn't change it -- so make the copy inside each function that alters the list so they don't change the original.

Comment: Hrm.  I didnt think about moving the copy's to inside the funtions.

Comment: but getDeriv needs the list from the first function.  I still think I see what you're saying though.

Comment: Even still.  The while loop should end.  When I use the visualizer its showing the while statement is getting below epsilon.  Thats how I knew I was on the right track.  So, I just threw a quick if in there, since the while wasnt doing it for me.